# When we invest in a corporation that has high capital expenditure every year but it is buying warehouses, is that less of a concern?

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation, capital-expenditure

I think the usual idea is that capital expenditure that goes to $0 value is not usually a good thing.  For example, if a company needs to buy 5 new fancy coffee maker for $800 every 5 years, and the old ones are sold as scrap metal.  (Or buy thousands of $2500 MacBook Pro for its workers and then 8 years later the computers are all recycled and sold for $50 each).

However, what if a corporation keeps on buying warehouses every year and needs to spend a lot of money?  Does that also goes into capital expenditure?

I usually find out the "owner's earning" by starting with net income and then add depreciation costs and then subtract capital expenditure.  Then I see this owner's earning as cash flow and judge how good the company is.  So if capital expenditure is high but is used to buy warehouses, then maybe we shouldn't subtract all of capital expenditure or maybe subtract only a fraction of it? Because what it buys (the warehouses) hold their values, and a company can easily stop buying (once they have all the warehouses they will ever need) and drastically reduce their capital expenditure in the future?

Comment: "(the warehouses) hold their values ..." — But warehouse buildings are depreciating assets that would eventually have to be replaced, just like the coffee machines and laptop computers that you mentioned.

Comment: Does "warehouses" include ownership of the land they stand on?

Comment: yes, the land included... you know how the company can buy the warehouse for $1 million today and 30 years later it is worth $2.5 million and the new owner may or may not just break down the building and build a new one?

Comment: Buying MacBook Pros is not a bad thing if they are needed for someone to do work that benefits the company, even if they are recycled 8 years later

Answer (score 2):

"Capital Expenditure" is just a term for "buying assets", which show up on the balance sheet, as opposed to *expenses*, which do not. Coffee makers are *probably* not considered "assets", but computers and warehouses certainly are.

What you seem to be calculating (start with income, add depreciation, subtract CapEx) is *cash flow*. It is a valuable calculation for many things, since income can be misleading if there are large non-cash expenses. But whether or not you think the investment is a *good idea* is largely irrelevant for cash flow calculation. It's still cash out the door - the *thing* that was bought just shows up as an asset. You can decide whether the business is being run well based on these types of investments, and there are other metrics that may measure that more objectively (e.g. Return on Assets)

So I would not recommend "adjusting" cash flow based on some subjective assessment of the expense - you need to know exactly how much cash was spent and on what (assets vs expenses vs financing). You can use *other* metrics to determine if cash is being spent *wisely*.

Comment: Coffee makers are most definitely assets, with longer useful life than a laptop even.

Comment: I doubt that companies are capitalizing them, though - if fact most companies I've worked for actually just leased them from a coffee vendor.

Comment: But your point is taken - _anything_ that's treated as an asset on the books is a "capital expense"

Comment: Companies often times lease IT equipment from vendors as well, it's a large chunk of enterprise manufacturers' like HP or Dell revenue. For lessors that's an asset though, on the books, and if expensive enough - depreciated over time (I think for tax and for IFRS/GAAP purposes, the "enough" may be different).

Comment: Very true (though I'm not sure where you're going :) )  My main point is that capex should not be discarded or discounted because it's subjectively "good" or "bad" - there are other ways of objectively measuring the "quality" of capex.

Comment: Agreed. I'm basically correcting the misconception that "small" or "inexpensive" assets are not capital assets - they are. There are companies whose main business is leasing computers, or coffee machines, and they'll be buying them all year every year, and racking up CAPEX - without understanding the business model of the company, looking at capex is useless.